# vsFTPd config error when using local_root=

Tags: sftp, ftp, selinux, vsftpd

What I am trying to achieve is the following, vsFTPd server which uses a different directory on a different mounted disk and jails each user to that directory while TLS/SSL is forced.

Currently I have the vsFTPd server running with chroot jail to each users local /home/$USER directory. This works with TLS/SSL configured. All good from this point.

Config file

```
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
local_umask=022
dirmessage_enable=YES
xferlog_std_format=YES
chroot_local_user=YES
allow_writeable_chroot=YES
user_sub_token=$USER
local_root=/home/$USER
#local_root=/media/ftp/data
listen=NO
listen_ipv6=YES
pam_service_name=vsftpd
userlist_enable=YES
pasv_min_port=30000
pasv_max_port=31000
userlist_file=/etc/vsftpd/user_list
userlist_deny=NO
#allow_anon_ssl=NO
#force_local_data_ssl=YES
#force_local_logins_ssl=YES
#rsa_cert_file=/etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.pem
#rsa_private_key_file=/etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.pem
#ssl_enable=YES
```

All is well till i change the local_root path to the following,

```
local_root=/media/ftp/data
```

/ftp  is the mount point for the disk.
/data is the diretory for all data and users.

Now i understand that chroot does very strange things but I have tried a number of different things which i have read online but I am still unsuccessful.

Here are a number of things I have tried.

1. I have commented out TLS/SSL completely and left this off in the congif file till I resolve this directory issue.
2. I have commented out chroot_local_user=YES, allow_writeable_chroot=YES, user_sub_token=$USER, local_root=/home/$USER and just changed the local_root=/media/ftp/data which gives me the error when using filezlla error "unable to change direcorty". Now I thought this would just be a simple permissions error but i changed all folders for testing to 777 but this did not help with the error.
3. I tried changing the users HOME directory and this gave me the same error as above.
4. I have turned off SELINUX and ON which returns the same result.
5. I have also tryed setting the setsebool but this is deprecated but I tested anyway which resulted in the same error.

I am deep into this and everything is a blur so any outside ideas would be great!?

Cheers

Edit1:

Filezilla error: 500 OOPS: cannot change directory:/media/ftp/data

Comment: I pondered recently using vsftpd with chroot, but used proftpd with chroot instead because it offers more options. Eg: it can chroot to any directory, not just to $HOME. This also prevents the hypothetical security risk of chrooting to a writable user-controlled directory in case some software parts can be told that they see / (including /etc/passwd etc.)

Comment: Will take a look at prosftp. I feel I may have to go with that if what you say is true.